# How can I find the distribution of an itô diffusion given it's generator?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm having a lot of truble with those generators. So if we have an Itô diffusion (in $\mathbb R$ and $f,\sigma $ nice enough to have uniqueness of solution) $$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma (X_t)dB_t,$$
it's generator is given by $$Af(x)=b(x)f'(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma ^2(x)f''(x).$$

I know that will determine uniquely the distribution of $X_t$ but I really don't see how. Could someone explain how I can find the distribution from this ?

---

I tried to do a parallel with the ODE $dy=b(y)dx$. The generator would be $Af(x)=b(x)f'(x)$, but from this, I really don't see how to get information of $y$... something looks magic and not clear at all.

Comment: Note that the Dynkin formula $$ E_x[f(X_t)] = f(x) + E_x\left[\int_0^t Af(X_s) \,d s \right]$$ for $f \in C^2_0(\mathbb{R})$ actually determines the distribution of $X_t$.

Comment: I suppose the reason you don't see a straightforward Laplace transform such as $$ E_x\exp(-\lambda X_t) = \exp(tA)(e^{-\lambda \cdot})(x)$$ is that, $A$ being an unbounded operator, needs to be defined on a subset of $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ (e.g. $C^2_0$, all compactly supported twice differentiable functions on the real line) and this smaller subset may not accommodate functions such as $x \mapsto e^{-\lambda x}.$

Comment: **Q1)** In dynkin formula,  must be a stopping time, no ? But still, from this formula, how can you get the distribution ? (I guess you'll mean Porte-menteau theorem, but in Porte-manteau theorem, we require bounded function (that is much bigger than $\mathcal C^2_0$).**Q2)** Sorry, but I don't see the point with Laplace transform. Maybe you can put it as an answer and not a comment ?@Sayantan

Comment: A fixed time is also a stopping time with finite mean, so Dynkin formula holds for $t$. Second, the reason that functions of $C^2_0(\mathbb{R})$ determine the distribution of $X_t$ is that $C^2_0(\mathbb{R})$ is a *separating class* of functions for $M_f(\mathbb{R})$ (the collection of finite Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}$). I'm using theorem 13.11 in Achim Klenke's *Probability Theory :
A Comprehensive Course* as a reference on this.

Comment: You may notice a small problem here: Klenke's theorem 13.11 only shows that $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ (compactly supported continuous functions) is a separtaing class for $M(\mathbb{R})$. But his proof can be suitably modified by smoothing out the $\rho_{K,\epsilon}$'s to make them twice differentiable instead of just Lipschitz.

Comment: Ok thanks (this notions are a bit advanced for me). But at the end, what is going to be the distribution of a stochastic process given its generator ? How could you find the distribution of the itô diffusion of $Af(x)=f''(x)+f'(x)$ or of $\sqrt{x}f''(x)+\sin(x)f'(x)$ for example ? @Sayantan

Comment: If you are referring to a closed form and nice formula for the distribution of $X_t$, I truly don't know how to derive one. This was the point I was trying to make with the Laplace transform comment: Having a formula of the Laplace transform will answer your question in full, but one will face some technical difficulties in order to get it.

Comment: @Sayantan: I see, thank you :)